# Conditionally include in fields for presto query

Tags: sql, presto

I have a presto query which works as expected:

```
SELECT json_format(cast(MAP(ARRAY['random_name'],
           ARRAY[
             MAP(
                ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c'],
                ARRAY[a, b, c]
            )]
) as JSON)) as metadata from a_table_with_a_b_c;  // a,b,c are all ints
```

Now I only want to include a,b,c when they are larger than 0, how do I change the query?  I can add 'CASE WHEN' but it seems I will have 'a:null' instead of not having it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`with rows as (
select row_number() over() as row_id, ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c'] as keys, ARRAY[a, b, c] as vals
from a_table_with_a_b_c 
)
select 
json_format(cast(MAP(ARRAY['random_name'],
  ARRAY[
    MAP(
        array_agg(key), array_agg(value)
  )]
) as JSON)) as metadata
from rows 
cross join unnest (keys, vals) as t (key, value)
where value is not null and value > 0
group by row_id;`